# "On Startup -> Open the New Tab page" not working; it is doing the "Continue where you left off" behavior

Tags: google-chrome

On two separate PC's now (current Chrome version I'm using is v39.0.2171.95 m) the "Open the New Tab page" functionality is not working.  If I close Chrome with, for example, 3 tabs open, when I reopen Chrome all three of those tabs are still open.

I've seen this before and am unsure of the fix.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Settings > On Startup and ensure that "Continue where you left off" is NOT selected.

You then have to go into your taskbar, right click on "Google Chrome" and exit. Only then will Chrome pick up the new settings. It should work when you reopen Chrome.

Comment: It just happened to me a few days ago, so I know what you're talking about. This is an issue with Chrome auto-updating itself and rewriting the settings internally despite the fact that your settings page shows whatever it shows now. Toggle it to "continue where you left off" and back to "open the new tab page", then save and **exit from taskbar**.

Comment: In my case I toggled the settings and went into the task manager and ended the Chrome process to get it to work.

Comment: I had same issue in all computer I work on now and @test answer was what did. I had to toggle between "continue where you left off" and back to "open new tab page", in Settings, and then kill the chrome processes through task manager. Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> advanced -> system 
and uncheck the setting:
"Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"

Comment: That's an important answer. I toggling between "continue where you left off" and back to "open the new tab page" and then closing Chrome was not working. Maybe like this it does. I managed to toggle through killing Chrome with task manager.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no other Chrome windows are open.

In my case I was using the Todoist extension which includes a "pop out window". This window appears on the taskbar as a Todoist window but it's actually a Chrome window. Hence when Chrome appears to be closed it's not actually closed, so the tabs don't close and they reappear when Chrome is reopened.

Answer (score 0):

For any macOS users that land here, I think toggling the "On startup" setting to "Continue where you left off", completely quitting, toggling it back to your desired "Open the New Tab page", and completely quitting again should do the trick.

I went off what's been mentioned with Chrome possibly having a disconnect between the shown and internal settings ("Open the New Tab page" was already set when I first looked), and needing to be quit from the Windows task bar to pick them up. Not sure how I would confirm unless it breaks again but I think toggling the option and quitting is key. I've definitely quit Chrome, reset my Mac, and upgraded Chrome all while it's been doing the "Continue where you left off" behavior, and still "Open the New Tab page" was what it showed me when I looked at the setting. Toggling it without quitting had no effect, it still kept doing the "Continue where you left off" behavior.